# PHP - object array into json

Tags: php, arrays, json

array of $setting['accountType'] :

```
$setting['accountType']['all'] = 'ALL';
$setting['accountType']['A1'] = 'VIP1';
$setting['accountType']['A2'] = 'VIP2';
```

PHP code to generate the object:

```
$object = new stdClass();
    $myArray = array();
    foreach ($setting['accountType'] as $key => $val)
    {                       
        $object->id = $key;
        $object->desc = $val;
        $myArray[] = $object;       
    }
    $accountType = $myArray;
```

PHP code to format object into json:

```
json_encode(['accountType'=> [(object)$accountType]));
```

However, i get the output as below :

```
"accountType": [{
    "0": {
        "id": "A2",
        "desc": "VIP"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "A2",
        "desc": "VIP"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "A2",
        "desc": "VIP"
    }
}]
```

***Problem 1: why $accountType only keep the last object when I loop through?***

***Problem 2: without the array key of $accountType*** [solved by using array_values($accountType)]

This is something that I am trying to achieve:

```
"accountType": [{
        "id": "all",
        "desc": "All "
    }, {
        "id": "A1",
        "desc": "Normal"
    }, {
        "id": "A2",
        "desc": "VIP"
    }]
```

How to get the output as above?

Comment: Why do you want it to be an object of `stdClass`?

Comment: Can you print $setting['accountType']  ?

Comment: `json_encode(['accountType'=> $accountType]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
json_encode(['accountType'=> $accountType]);
```

instead of

```
json_encode(['accountType'=> [(object)$accountType]]);
```

In your code you are putting `$accountType` inside another array that is why you are getting that result

Here is a [Demo and Explanation](https://eval.in/709243)

Edit: The entire code

```
$setting['accountType']['all'] = 'ALL';
$setting['accountType']['A1'] = 'VIP1';
$setting['accountType']['A2'] = 'VIP2';

$myArray = array();
foreach ($setting['accountType'] as $key => $val)
{                       
    $object = new stdClass(); // Note: $object should be created inside the loop
    $object->id = $key;
    $object->desc = $val;
    $myArray[] = $object;       
}
$accountType = $myArray;
echo json_encode(['accountType'=> $accountType]);
```

And Here is the [Revised Demo](https://eval.in/709257)

Comment: why i get the repeating value when I loop through the $setting['accountType'], and assign to $dealStatus ?

Comment: you mean in the demo? there the date is just for sample and have repeated it 3 times to have more data. The loop you use to generate is fine just use `json_encode(['accountType'=> $dealStatus]);`.

Comment: i have amended the demo , and you can see it only keep {"id":"A1","desc":"VIP1"} , and the first object {"id":"A2","desc":"VIP"} is missing from $accountType

Comment: I have edited and added a new demo with the data in the question.

Comment: @bansi please [review carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14833111)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
echo json_encode(array_values($your_array));
```

Let me know if its working

Comment: @V for Vendetta ok, this is part of the answer I am looking for ... thx

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the same thing, no?
The numerotation is displayed because you need it to access to the specific json object.
You have an array and you can access to each element by its key.